Does the accuracy of the iterations of the Newton method transfer to parts of the underlying non-linear equation system?
I'm just wondering one thing. Suppose I have a non-linear system of equations $F(z) = z - d(z) = 0$ for $F: \mathbb{R}^{n} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n}$. If I apply a Newton method with respect to $F(z)$ for an initial intital value $z_0$, iterations $z_k$ result for $k = 1,2, \dots$. If I terminate this Newton method with a termination condition $\lVert F(z_k) \rVert < \epsilon$, can I then say something about $\lVert F(d(z_k)) \rVert$ with respect to $\epsilon$?

Do not use this criteria; Multiply $F(z_k)$ by $10^{-12345}$ and the problem is solved

It is an good criteria if used correctly. A good example is the case where $r = r(\theta)$ denotes the range of shell fired from a gun with elevation $\theta$. Solving $r(\theta) = d$ is equivalent to computing the firing solution for a target at distance $d$ from the gun. With $f(\theta) = d - r(\theta)$ we see that terminating any iteration when $|f(\theta)| \leq \rho$, where $\rho$ is the kill radius of the shell, will ensure that the target is destroyed. As for your question, I believe that more information about your $F$ is needed. Do you have extra assumptions?
